# Picking up an array from the top right

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pick up a 2D array (representing a pile of cards) from the top right most column, and then put it back into a 1D array to emulate a sort of 'shuffling' effect but am encountering some problems.

Here is my code

```
for (int r = 0; r < deck.length; r++) {
    for (int c = (deck[r].length - 1); c == 0; c--) {
        pile[k] = deck[r][c];
        k++;
    }
}
```

But this just ends up printing out the array in the original order.

Comment: Can you show me your input and out put you want?

Comment: Lets say there is a pile of cards from 1 -6 with a row length of 3. The output of picking it up and putting it down from the top right (which is what im trying to do) should be 3 2 1 4 5 6 , where it was orginally  1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: I think instead of c == 0 in second loop, you have c> = 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you want "c != 0;".  That condition in an if statement is "loop while this statement is true" but it looks like you're treating it as "loop *until* this statement is true."

Currently I don't think you're entering the second loop since c is starting out > 0.

Comment: Thank you, it has changed the output but still not the correct output. I want the output to be 3 2 1 4 5 6, but the output is now 3 2 6 5 5 6

Answer (score 0):

Lê Hoàng Dững had the right answer, I had to change

```
c == 0 to c >= 0
```